# SQL beginner - Why does my MySQL Join-query use no index / work so slow?

Tags: sql, join, indexing

I got the following problem with my MySQL 5.5 DB - i am pretty new to this so it might be very obvious whats wrong but i just cant seem to get it:

Two tables:

---

Table1

```
CREATE TABLE `sequence_matches` (
    `Sample_ID` INT(6) NOT NULL,
    `Sequence_Match_ID` INT(8) NOT NULL,
    `Start` INT(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `End` INT(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Coverage` DOUBLE(5,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Frag_String` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `rms_mass_error_prod` DOUBLE(10,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `rms_rt_error_prod` DOUBLE(10,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Sample_ID`, `Sequence_Match_ID`)
)
```

---

and

---

Table 2

```
CREATE TABLE `peptide_identifications` (
   `Sample_ID` INT(6) NOT NULL,
   `Peptide_identification_ID` INT(8) NOT NULL,
   `Mass_error` DOUBLE(10,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `Mass_error_ppm` DOUBLE(10,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `Score` DOUBLE(10,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `Type` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `global_pept_ID` INT(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Sample_ID`, `Peptide_identification_ID`),
  INDEX `Index` (`global_pept_ID`)
)
```

---

each of them contains ~15 million rows.

Now, i want all those rows from `Table2` where `global_pept_id = 27443` and then use the `peptide_identification_id` of those, to query all information from `Table1` where `peptide_identification_id = sequence_match_id`.

I tried the following statement:

```
SELECT * from sequence_matches 
JOIN (
  SELECT peptide_identification_id 
  FROM peptide_identifications 
  WHERE global_pept_id = 27443
) as tmp_pept 
ON sequence_match_id = peptide_identification_id;
```

Here the Explain for that query:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QV3ER.jpg] (click to enlarge)

Now this query is very, very slow (i actually never finished it, stopepd it after ~10min) and i can imagine it's because there is no Index used for the second table although both ID's are primary key and thus they should be indexed right?

The results for the inner select require ~3 sek and return ~3k rows if performed alone. So the i think the problem is making 3000 * 15mio compares cause every row is checked in Table2.

But how do i fix this?

any help appreciated
-voiD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly different than other solutions.  Consider the primary criteria you are trying to get first... those peptide elements for a given global peptide value.  Ensure you have an index on this table on any such criteria you may be querying against (which you have).  However, if you find you will be querying on more than one WHERE condition against the same table, try to prepare/have an index that will help on BOTH criteria.

Then, put a JOIN condition to the other table on the PK/FK relationship to get those records.

```
SELECT * 
   from 
      peptide_identification PI
         JOIN sequence_matches SM
            ON PI.peptide_identification_id = SM.sequence_match_id
   WHERE 
      PI.global_pept_id = 27443
```

Without having proper indexes can significantly kill a query's performance.  Your Sequence_Matches table should have an index on just (Sequence_match_ID) to help its optimization.  Having it in the second position (after the sample_id), will not benefit as expected.

Comment: Your answer is nearly correct; having an column in the second position of the index will not benefit at all.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably because you're joining on a subquery. Try:

```
SELECT sm.*, pi.peptide_identification_id
FROM sequence_matches sm
INNER JOIN peptide_identifications pi
ON sm.id = pi.peptide_identification_id
WHERE pi.global_pept_id = 27443
```

Comment: +1 You could share with OP about the `join` and `inner join` ;) as well

Answer (score 0):

A tipp would be to avoid subselects. Sometimes they are great, but usually result in poor performance. A better way might be:

```
SELECT * from peptide_identification as tmp_pept
JOIN sequence_matches  
    ON sequence_matches.sequence_match_id = tmp_pept.peptide_identification_id
WHERE tmp_pept.global_pept_id = 27443
```

Does that do the trick?

Edit: No, the real problem is that there is no index on sequence_match_id. Add one and you'll probably be fine.

Comment: No, still the same. I did test it for ~2min with no result. Also the Explain for that query without any subselect is the same as with subselect - it's still not using any index for matching my 3000 vs. 15million rows.

Comment: I Updated my answer; you have no index on the column you use for the join! (it has to be the FIRST column of the index)

Comment: So having a primary key as index for sample_id + sequence_match_id does not cover for that? Does that mean i should make an index for every column i plan to query?

Comment: Yes and no, if you query for sample_id and sequence_match_id at the same time, your actual index is exactly what you need. If you query for sample_id, your actual index will also work, but not for sequence_match_id. Yes, you need an extra index.

Comment: There also was a slight logical error made by me, it should read `ON sequence_matches.sequence_match_id = tmp_pept.peptide_identification_id AND sequence_matches.sample_id = tmp_pept.Sample_ID`

Sorry for that ^^

Now its using the primary key as index just as i thought it should - but many thanks for the clarification about indexes in general

/* 0 rows affected, 3.148 rows found. Duration for 1 query: 1,528 sec. (+ 21,825 sec. network) */

Comment: Very good, nice that it helped you. DRapp was the first who found the missing index, i saw that after editing my answer. His answer should have been choosen!

Answer (score 0):

> i think the problem could be because u r now creating a cross join
>   instead of an inner join. your subquery is creating a cartesian
>   product of 15 million rows * 3 million rows.
>
> using an inner join you wud reduce that number to 15 million*3000
>   rows.
>
> it is still a huge number. At the Sql end u can restrict it by issuing
>   a TOP 10 or TOP 20.
>
> At the front end, if it is C# u should use paging techniques like
>   gridviewpager or other paging techniques on the datasource assuming u
>   are going to display the result at the front end which will sit on top
>   of your SQL Join Query and page 20 results at a time.